# Trying to integrate a list of years within a dynamic field input with native javascript

Tags: javascript, html, dynamic

I've done quite a bit of searching on this website and have come up with two methods I'd like to use together.  Based on other programming experience it appears to me that I need to nest the functions I'm using.

The two functions I want to use together are

1. creation of dynamic inputs based on a total number of children and
2. a select list of automatically updating years that can be selected, once the dynamic fields are created based on from the number of children are created.

I'm struggling a bit with this, based on my limited JavaScript experience and could use a little bit of help.

Here's the code I have so far and there are issues with the year "select list" being generated for each child field created.

```js
function addinputFields() {
  var number = document.getElementById("child").value;
  while (container.hasChildNodes()) {
    container.removeChild(container.lastChild);
  }

  for (i = 0; i < number; i++) {

    container.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Child " + (i + 1)));

    var input = document.createElement("input");
    var min = new Date().getFullYear() - 40;
    cur = new Date().getFullYear();
    select = document.getElementById('year');
    for (var a = min; a <= cur; a++) {
      var opt = document.createElement('option');
      opt.value = a;
      opt.text = a;
      select.appendChild(opt);
    }
    input.type = "text";
    input.name = "Child" + i;
    container.appendChild(input);
  }
}
```

```html
<div>
  <label for="child">Number of Children:</label>
  <input id="child" type="text" name="child" value="" size="3" style="margin-left:15px;text-align:center;">
</div>

<div>
  <button class="kb" onclick="addinputFields()">Add</button>
</div>

<p>Input Kindergarten Start Years</p>
<div id="container">
</div>

<select id="year">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I am understood from your problem you are facing problem in selected year list. So I have done some changes in your code, it will help you if would be that you are looking for.

```
function addinputFields() {
  var number = document.getElementById("child").value;
  while (container.hasChildNodes()) {
    container.removeChild(container.lastChild);
  }

  for (i = 0; i < number; i++) {

    container.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Child " + (i + 1)));

    var input = document.createElement("input");
    var selectList = document.createElement("select");
    selectList.id = "year"+(i+1);

    var min = new Date().getFullYear() - 40;
    cur = new Date().getFullYear();
    select = document.getElementById('year');
    for (var a = min; a <= cur; a++) {
      var opt = document.createElement('option');
      opt.value = a;
      opt.text = a;
      selectList.appendChild(opt);
    }
    input.type = "text";
    input.name = "Child" + i;
    container.appendChild(input);
    container.appendChild(selectList);
  }
}
```

Comment: This is very close and I appreciate the quick response.  What I'm trying to do is have the year select lists be the only thing created once I add the number of children I want.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to tweak your tweak of my code and now it does exactly what I want...

Thanks again for all the help!!!

```js
function addinputFields() {
  var number = document.getElementById("child").value;
  while (container.hasChildNodes()) {
    container.removeChild(container.lastChild);
  }

  for (i = 0; i < number; i++) {

    container.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Child " + (i + 1)));

    var input = document.createElement("input");
    var selectList = document.createElement("select");
    selectList.id = "year"+(i+1);

    var min = new Date().getFullYear() - 40;
    cur = new Date().getFullYear();
    select = document.getElementById('year');
    for (var a = min; a <= cur; a++) {
      var opt = document.createElement('option');
      opt.value = a;
      opt.text = a;
      selectList.appendChild(opt);
    }
    container.appendChild(selectList);
  }
}
```

```html
<div>
        <label for="child">Number of Children:</label>
        <input id="child" type="text" name="child" value="" size="3" style="margin-left:15px;text-align:center;">
    </div>

    <div>
        <button class="kb" onclick="addinputFields()">Add</button> 
    </div> 

    <p>Input Kindergarten Start Years</p>
    <div id="container">
    </div>
```